# Not able to execute below prime no program

Tags: primes

I am trying write a simple prime number code from 1 to 100, but I am unable to understand why its not giving me result.

```
package com.java.program;

public class PrimeNo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Prime no btw 1 to 100");

        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            int  count=0;
            for(int j=2;j<=i;j++){
                if(i%j==0)
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count==0)
            {
                System.out.println("\t" +i);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prints 1, as expected, for me. Try it with table, pencil and paper: What is i, what j. You can do it in a spreadsheet too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first for loop start i from 2 instead of 1. In your second for loop you are doing (j <= i). A number is always divisible by itself and hence it makes count++ and it is ignored when j = i. Try this (j < i) or for efficiency (j <= i/2+1).

Answer (score 1):

just do j< i and it will print. because the number n will always be divisible by n so its not printing primes between 2 and 100

```
for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
```

Comment: better to run the j-loop till i/2 or sqrt(i)

Comment: well spotted. Suggestions for improving the code beyond what the OP is asking do belong in the answer (as long as you *also* answer the question, which you do); so I suggest you edit your answer and add some version of what you say in your comment.